# Retrieve data from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows,

```
Id             Form_Id     Form_Layout_Txt
-------------- ----------- -----------------
2              1           aa
3              1           bb
5              2           dddd
6              2           eeeee
7              3           fffff
8              3           gggg
```

i need to retreive the rows which has same Form_id as follows,

```
2              1           aa
3              1           bb
```

How to write a query for the above data?

Thanks

Comment: From Where does the `ID` 4 come from?

Comment: I suggest you stop what you are doing and get a good book on SQL and database basics. You can also get a good start at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: Sigh! that's all you needed? :$

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * 
from nameoftable 
where  Form_Id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need at most basic level, unless there's a hidden immunity to find out more :)

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR TABLE 
WHERE FORM_ID = 1
```